# Alternate way to symbolize there is exactly one

Tags: logic

So we all know the common way of denoting there is exactly one in First Order Logic: ∃x[(A(x) ∧ ∀y(A( y) → y = x)) ∧ B(x)]

But, I was thinking and I wonder if there is another way to do it. Like let's day we were symbolizing there is exactly one dog (Dx) from a domain of animals. If I say ∀x∀y((D(x)&D(y)) ->x=y), will this also symbolize there is exactly one dog? I think so but as this way has not been explored in any text I have seen, I can't be sure. So, can anyone explain whether this is right or why it may be wrong

Comment: No, it symbolizes there is at most one dog. It would be satisfied if there are no dogs.

Comment: In the first formula, ∧B(x) should be removed. The second formula would work if you add ∧∃zD(z) to it. Wikipedia gives [four equivalent FOL formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification#Reduction_to_ordinary_existential_and_universal_quantification) for unique existence, including these two as corrected.

Comment: @causative Thank you. For some reason, I always forget to consider that something may not exist